# Ramp signal python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to generate a ramp signal to 0 to 5 V so I use the function sawtooth waveform and it has a period 2*pi, rises from -1 to 1 but how can I do to change the rising to 0 and 5?

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib notebook

Fs = 1000000
f1 = 5  
timePoints = np.linspace(0, 1, Fs)
ramp = 5*signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * f1 * timePoints)
plt.plot(timePoints, ramp)
```

Comment: `ramp = np.abs(5*signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * f1 * timePoints))` might solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to work with output of existing function, you can add 1 to the output of sawtooth to make it go from 0 to 2.
if you want it to go from 0 to 5, you can multiply the above output with 5/2.

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
plt.plot(t, 2.5*(signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * t) + 1))
```

Comment: nooooo, don't multiply it in a list comprehension! Do `2.5 * (signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 5 * t) + 1)` instead.

Comment: my bad, just saw the code of sawtooth, return value is numpy array.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work